# Oracle reports 6i: REP-1814: Report cannot be formatted. Object 'vertically' can never fit within

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I'm using Oracle reports 6i, and when trying to print a report from a form, it gets me this error:

```
REP-1814: Report cannot be formatted. Object 'vertically' can never fit within 'R_Empressa'
```

and this this where 'R_empressa' is placed:
[image]

what might be the problem here?

Comment: There is a My Oracle Support document which corresponds closely titled, "Rep-1814: Report Cannot be Formatted, Object 'Vertically' Can Never Fit Within ' ' (Doc ID 368710.1)".  It refers to newer versions of Oracle Reports.

Comment: @PatrickBacon where do i find this document?

Comment: Well, you need a My Oracle Support account which you should have a support identifier from your employer (here are some details about requesting an account, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E74665_01/MSREG/toc.htm#CEGCIFIF).  Here is the URL for My Oracle Support, https://support.oracle.com.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check whether all frames' vertical elasticities are correctly set; if "inner" frame is set to be variable, while "outer" frame is *fixed*, if inner frame contains a lot of data, it can't stretch enough because outer frame won't let it. Obviously, you should set outer frame to be *variable* as well.

Answer (score -1):

The text that will be loaded inside the field "R_Empressa" is bigger then your width size. resize the field or set your property "vertical Elasticity" to "Expand".